# C# SQLite multiple keyword with like command

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I used SQLite. The user will pull the days from checkbox and I'll show it in data grid view but the date is recorded as day and time so I have to  use like instead of in command.

[image]

```
        DataSet dataSet122;
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source =log.sqlite;Version=3;");
        string search = checkBoxComboBox1.Text;
        string[] array = search.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = "'" + array[i] + "'";
        }
        string names = String.Join(",", array);
        listBox2.Items.Add(names);
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Gemkay1 WHERE ZAMAN LIKE  (" + names + ")";
        command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
        dataSet122 = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataSet122, "Gemkay1");
        dataGridViewSummary1.DataSource = dataSet122.Tables["Gemkay1"];
```

Comment: In addition to the answer below, please don't use string concatenation to build SQL statements, use parameters. Google it for how to do it with C# and SQLite.

Comment: not knowing how many days the user will choose, so I assigned the days to an array, but how can I show them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [IN](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-in/)  operator to select data where multiple values

```
"SELECT * FROM Gemkay1 WHERE ZAMAN IN ('2021-02-01','2021-02-02')";
```

to ignore time from date you can use `date` function:

```
"SELECT * FROM Gemkay1 WHERE date(ZAMAN) IN ('2021-02-01','2021-02-02')";
```

See [SQLite date and time functions documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I tried this SELECT * FROM Gemkay1 WHERE date(ZAMAN) LIKE. If I choose 1 day it works, but if I choose more than 1, it gives an error. This is my error SQL logic error row value misused'

Comment: use IN not Like

Comment: I can't use IN command because ZAMAN column consists of date and time. For example  2021-02-01 14:38:00 but I just have to search by date.

Comment: use date function "date(ZAMAN) IN (....)" to ignore time in date

Comment: No, date function removes time from saman column so IN will work

Comment: Try to avoid calling functions on table data- it usually kills the ability to use an index on the column making searching slow

Comment: I used date function "date(ZAMAN) IN (....)" ıt work thanks a lot

Comment: So now your sql could have two problems.. Not SARGable and SQL injection :/ - be sure at least to fix the sql injection one (use the parameters concatenating technique from my answer)

Comment: @oguzhanoztrk why you set the answer as accepted and then remove it ! :)

Comment: @CaiusJard i agree with you about the SQL injection ... but it's a sample answer for his question

Comment: @NajiMakhoul I'm sorry I only accepted 1 answer but Caius jard's answer is work too. I use your solution thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL syntax for all people where name ends with SMITH or WRIGHT:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%SMITH' OR name LIKE '%WRIGHT'
```

LIKE is not the same as IN - it accepts a single string argument on the right hand side. If you want multiple LIKEs you must repeat the LIKE clause separated by OR

IN can be used with multiple string but it does not accept wildcards:

```
WHERE name IN ('playwright', 'cartwright', 'shipwright')
```

If you try and put a wildcard in it will literally match that character.

-

As an aside, don't make SQL like you're doing there, with string concatenation of the values. Concatenate parameters in instead and give them values, for example:

```
var names = new []{"%wright", "%smith"};

var sql = new SqliteCommand("SELECT * FROM t WHERE 1=0 ");

for(int p = 0; p<names.Length; p++){
  sql.CommandText += " OR name like @p" + p;
  sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p"+p, names[p]);
}
```

This I what I mean when I say "concatenate parameters in, then give them a value".

If you ever work with sqlserver read [this blog post](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it won't work for me beacuse if user chooses 10 days I have to use 10 OR. The code must be dynamic according to the user's choice.

Comment: The reason I can't use the IN command is that the column I search has date and time , so I'm only searching by date, so I have to use LIKE command

Comment: Then you have to use it like I say

Comment: Yes I have to use LIKE but I dont know how many days the user chose.

Comment: For example If user choose 10 days LIKE day1 OR LIKE day2...... its not good

Comment: Doesn't matter how many days the user chooses; that's what loops are for. See my edit. Imagine that my names array is from the user and contains 500 things. The loop will just make 500 ORs

Comment: *its not good* - what do you think the IN operator does internally? You've set the requirement of 10 days, you need to use 9 ORs, unless they're in a range and then you can use BETWEEN (and that only works for range-able things)